# Altium Polygon Pour gap - minimum feature clearance rule?

Tags: altium, cad, polygon

Didn't find anyone covering this.
On this image I'm showing a GND Polygon pour artifact that I cannot seem Altium to detect that gap is too narrow.

Polygons are:
Remove Islands less than 0.2 sq.mms area
Arc approx: 0.025mm
Remove necks width less than: 0.2mm

Signal clearance rules make the pour bleed away 0.15mm.

**That particular pour gap is 0.015mm wide - manufacturer cannot produce such feature!**

[image: Polygon pour gap]

Ok, for a) manufacturer will ignore this (somehow) and provides no guarantee how much the copper will bleed away from that particular place.
b)
Sure, easy fix for that particular spot is to move the via and allow polygon to fill
BUT
I must look and Find them manually - If I get lucky I find them.

**Anyone has experience on How to make Altium find such pouring artefacts and report them ?**

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to search for such artifacts. However, to find the place you can search the net VIN_#EN, and I’m sure you’ll eventually find it (them). Then you can shelve the pour and re-route the tracks with a rounded track to avoid the corner. Otherwise have you tried reducing the “Remove necks width less than: 0.2mm” to 0.15mm or less and re-pouring the polygon? Generally, manufacturers will be able to etch necks < 0.1mm (or whatever the minimum track they’ll do).

Comment: @citizen Well I'm sure it's not specific to only that net. It can be near any net - that's why I was wondering maybe there is a clearance rule that I can apply :)

But yes, that seems to be correct that Altium somehow measures or acts differently around corners as it needs slightly bigger clearance to go around the corners (especially that are 45 deg).

Uff, very well, if someone else won't point smth out as well, I go back into 3D mode and in single layer mode, tediously checking entire copper (I've found that in 3D mode such artifacts reveal themselves a bit more easily).

Comment: If its really a show-stopper or time-waster it may be worth getting some specific assistance from Altium, either from their technical support or on the forum...

Comment: When I run into polygon pours that are acting wonky, I'll lay little bits of track with the same node name anywhere I find the wonkyness.

Comment: There's a setting in the polygon pour that allows you to have 'better' curves.  What you have above is segmented.   Increase the resolution of the pours.   You didn't say what version Altium so I can't tell you exactly what to look for, but it's in the polygon-pour window that pops up when you double-click on it.